# How to select the last lines of a uitableview with many items

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, view

I'm confused about a question on uitableview. As u know, uitableview is a subclass of scrollview and can contain may items. However, I'm not able to select the last lines of a uitableview with many items. For example, I initialize a uitableview with 100 items and only 20 items appears once. So if I want to choose the 90th or 100th item I have to scroll the uitableview. However, the uitableview always stop at the 75 item. Although I can scroll the view to the 90th item, I cannot select it, that is, everytime I want to click this line, the uitableview jump to the 75 item again.
  It is very confusing. Anyone have ideas about this question? Waiting for your ideas and help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the height of your tableview in nib. If the height is defined greater than the view size in which it is loading, this situation might occur.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the height of the table view in its frame. Try reducing the height of the table view.